# iwlist scan output format

Tags: python, linux, parsing, wifi

I have to write a tool to get the encryption type out of a iwlist scan. I just can't seem to find whether or not there's a standard output. Googling it looks like people are posting slightly different formats, but I can't tell if they just copy/pasted wrong or what. Specifically, in `Encryption key: On`, is `On`/`Off` frist letter always capitalized? How about `IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1`? Is the encryption always preceeded by `IEEE 802.11i/`?

I hope this is OK to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off parsing the contents of `/proc/net/wireless`, depending on what you need. [This](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Linux.Wireless.Extensions.html) will help get you started. The fields are all the same, but the values can differ from driver to driver and device to device. So no, you probably can't rely on spelling to be consistent, and capitalization even less so.

Answer (score 3):

As `/proc/net/wireless` is just showing information about the current WLAN connection, I adapted a script to contain encryption information necessary to e.g. feed `wpa_supplicant`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do

    ## Reset variables on new network
    [[ "$line" =~ Cell || "$line" == "" ]] && {

        # If no WPA encryption info was found though "Encryption" was "On", then we have WEP
        [[ "$encryption" == "" && "$enc" =~ On ]] && encryption = "WEP"

        # If we already found one network then echo its information
        [[ "$network" != "" ]] && echo "$network [$encryption]"
        network=""
        encryption=""
    }

    ## Test line content and parse as required
    [[ "$line" =~ Address ]] && mac=${line##*ss: }
    [[ "$line" =~ \(Channel ]] && { chn=${line##*nel }; chn=${chn:0:$((${#chn}-1))}; }
    [[ "$line" =~ Frequen ]] && { frq=${line##*ncy:}; frq=${frq%% *}; }
    [[ "$line" =~ Quality ]] && {
        qual=${line##*ity=}
        qual=${qual%% *}
        lvl=${line##*evel=}
        lvl=${lvl%% *}
    }

    ## Encryption is "On" if WEP or WPA, otherwise it's "Open"
    [[ "$line" =~ Encrypt ]] && enc=${line##*key:}
    [[ "$enc" =~ Off ]] && {
        [[ "$encryption" != "" ]] && encryption="${encryption},"
        encryption="${encryption}Open"
    }

    ## The ESSID is the last line of the basic channel data, so build information string now
    [[ "$line" =~ ESSID ]] && {
        essid=${line##*ID:}
        network="$mac  $essid  $frq  $chn  $qual  $lvl  $enc"  # output after ESSID
    }

    ## WPA encryption information
    [[ "$line" =~ WPA ]] && wpa=${line##*WPA} && {
        [[ "$encryption" != "" ]] && encryption="${encryption}|"
        encryption="${encryption}WPA$wpa"
    }
    [[ "$line" =~ "Group Cipher" ]] && encryption="$encryption,${line##*: }"
    [[ "$line" =~ "Pairwise Cipher" ]] && encryption="$encryption,${line##*: }"
    [[ "$line" =~ "Authentication Suites" ]] && encryption="$encryption,${line##*: }"

done < <(iwlist wlan0 scan 2>/dev/null )
```

The scripts output (example):

```
34:81:C7:EB:24:89  "cyberdyne"  2.462  11  67/70  -43  on [WPA2 Version 1,CCMP,CCMP,PSK]
36:81:C7:EB:24:89  "cyberguest"  2.462  11  65/70  -45  on [WPA2 Version 1,TKIP,CCMP,PSK|WPA Version 1,TKIP,TKIP,PSK]
```

If there are multiple encryption mechanisms available for the SSID then they are separated by `"|"`.

Comment: This is very nicely done. You can easily narrow down the information you want from this script by commenting out the `network=` line and creating your own with just the variables you want. You can also remove the `[$encryption]` part of `echo "$network [$encryption]"` if you want to get rid of the encryption type details.